# Modular forms with finitely many or very few non-zero Fourier coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

I have an elementary question on modular forms, but which I don't know how to solve.

> a) Is there a congruence subgroup $\Gamma \leq \mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)$, an integer $k \in \Bbb Z$ and a non-constant modular form $f \in M_k(\Gamma)$ such that $f$ has only finitely many non-zero Fourier coefficients $a_n(f)$ ?
>
> b) What about $\{n \geq 0 \mid  a_n(f) \neq 0\}$ having zero density?

One can easily have a non-zero modular form $f$ such that $a_n(f) = 0$ for every odd integer $n$. For part a), I think the answer should be no : $f$ is just a trigonometric polynomial and I guess one can come up with some elementary argument, but I don't know exactly how. Part b) is maybe a more subtle question, I would be glad to have any information about it!

I already asked it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4113252/), but got no comment nor any reply. Possibly related: [Modular forms with prime Fourier coefficients zero](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25461/modular-forms-with-prime-fourier-coefficients-zero).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, any modular form gives rise to a degree $2$ L-function. So if you can prove the corresponding L-function has impossible properties, you're done.

Comment: For (a), one should exclude $k=0$. If $k \neq 0$, there will be a linear dependence relation between the derivatives $f$, $Df$, $D^2 f$... The function $D^m f$ is a quasi-modular form of weight $k+2m$ and it is known that the algebra generated by quasi-modular forms decomposes as a direct sum according to the weight, which should imply $f=0$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For simplicity, I will assume that $f$ is a cusp form (hence $k\geq 12$ and $k$ is even).

The answer to question (a) is negative. It was proved independently by [Rankin (1939)](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100021095) and Selberg (1940) that the Dirichlet series
$$\sum_n\frac{|a_n(f)|^2}{n^s}$$
has a simple pole at $s=k$. Hence infinitely many coefficients $a_n(f)$ are nonzero.

Regarding question (b), let me further assume that $f$ is a primitive Hecke eigenform. If $f$ is a CM form, then $a_n(f)\neq 0$ implies that the prime factors of the square-free part of $n$ split in the quadratic number field associated with $f$, so the density of $\{n:a_n(f)\neq 0\}$ is zero. If $f$ is not a CM form, then the density of $\{n:a_n(f)\neq 0\}$ is positive, as proved by [Serre (1981)](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=PMIHES_1981__54__123_0).

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. I'm not sure about the CM case: do you mean that the set of $n$ such that the prime factors of $n$ split in the quadratic number field associated with $f$ has density 0? Doesn't the set of products $p_{i_1} \cdots p_{i_k}$ (where each $p_j$ splits) have positive density?

Comment: @Alphonse: Those products don't have positive density. The number of such integers up to $x$ is asymptotically a constant times $x/\sqrt{\log x}$, as proved by Landau.

Comment: Just to clarify: Serre's non-lacunarity result (Théorème 17) applies to all modular forms, not just newforms.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: Thanks for your valuable comment!

Answer (score 14):

There is a completely elementary way to see that the answer to a) is negative - if $f$ had only finitely many Fourier coefficients, it would extend to an entire function on $\mathbb C$. But for any $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\in\Gamma$ we get
$$f\left(\frac{b}{d}\right)=f\left(\frac{a\cdot 0+b}{c\cdot 0+d}\right)=(c\cdot 0+d)^kf(0)=d^kf(0)$$
which means that either $f$ has a dense set on which it is constant (if $k=0$ or $f(0)=0$), and hence $f$ is constant, or $f$ will take arbitrarily high values within interval $(0,1)$, which is impossible.

The same argument, together with simple upper bouds on $a_n(f)$, also gives some, though admittedly bad, lower bounds on how many nonzero coefficients there ought to be - the nonzero coefficients cannot be exponentially sparse. GH from MO's answer gives a much tighter bounds in these regards.

Comment: Very nice argument for part a). +1. Thanks!